# Page order for right-to-left languages (Arabic, Hebrew)

Tags: xsl-fo

In most languages, books are made with the binding on the left side. The cover page is a right-side page, and a page spread consists of an even-numbered page on the left, and an odd-numbered page on the right. When you read the book in order, you flip the pages to the left.

In right-to-left (RTL) languages, this is reversed: books are made with the binding on the right side. The cover page is a left-side page, and a page spread consists of an even-numbered page on the right, and an odd-numbered page on the left. When you read the book in order, you flip the pages to the right.

I've created an FO template that will be used for multiple languages. I've used the writing-mode property to support the RTL languages.

According to this [RenderX tutorial:](http://www.renderx.com/tutorial.html)

> writing-mode property defines every aspect of the document organization: binding edge, column ordering in tables, text alignment in blocks, etc.

But I've found that's not entirely true for Antennahouse (6.1). 
Text alignment and column ordering all work correctly, but the binding edge is not implemented fully. The page order is still LTR.

I want to print a book in the correct page order for RTL languages:

1. the binding must be on the right
2. the first page of the PDF must be the last page of the book

Requirement 2. is there so I can print a multilanguage book with LTR languages at the front, and RTL languages at the back.

Now I could create a new layout-master-set for RTL languages to get the binding on the right side. After generating the PDF, I can reverse the page order of the PDF in Acrobat.

But is there a way to specify the correct page order in XSL-FO?
I'm using the Antennahouse renderer. This has the [axf.reverse-page](http://www.antennahouse.com/CSSInfo/extension.html#axf.reverse-page) custom property, but this only works within one page-sequence. My book has several page-sequences (one per chapter), so I can't use that.

I've spent some time digging through the specification, but haven't found anything that fits.

Comment: The XSL 1.1 Recommendation is unfortunately vague about how to determine the binding edge.  The definition of `fo:page-sequence` includes "This recommendation does not specify the mechanism for selecting which side is the page binding edge."  In theory you could infer the binding edge from the writing mode, but that falls down when you're doing something like a calendar, where the binding edge is at the top/bottom of the page.  FWIW, the XSL 2.0 Requirements document includes a requirement for being able to specify the binding edge (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20-req/#N66625).

Comment: How are you organizing the page numbers in the mixed RTL/LTR book?

Comment: The mixed book has page numbers in LTR format throughout the book. So English would be page 1-10 and Arabic would start on page 20 and end on page 11.

Comment: 'start' and 'end' are potentially ambiguous when you're changing writing modes. If you read the book as a LTR book, do the page numbers go '1, 2, ..., 9, 10, 11, 12, ..., 20' or '1, 2, ..., 9, 10, 20, 19, ..., 11'?

Comment: The page numbers go '1, 2, ..., 9, 10, 11, 12, ..., 20'. The first Arabic page is page 20, the second Arabic page is numbered 19. So someone who reads Arabic can read the book in the order that's natural to him.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-prevp` command-line parameter to print the pages in reverse order.  See http://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-xslcmd.html#prevp

Comment: Good point. I was hoping to control this from inside the XSL-FO, though: if I can do that, I can use a single template for all languages. If I have to include a separate processing instruction for RTL, that means 2 different preference files for Antennahouse and I'd have to change a simple process (start Antennahouse with its default preferences) to a process that includes conditional logic.

Comment: If your process allowed a pre-project Option Setting File for AH Formatter, then you could use one that specifies `reverse-page="true"` (http://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-optset.html#reverse-page) for your RTL project and specify one that doesn't for your other projects.  The command line parameters would be the same, but the contents of the Option Setting Files would be different.